# Что нужно знать для работы с хостингом?

Tags: хостинг, dns, домен

Выполнял заказ по вёрстке, всё хорошо сделал, заказчику понравилось, но были проблемы с привязкой домена к хостингу, получилось решить вопросы через поддержку (они сказали, что и где написать), но ушло много времени, хотелось бы самому разбираться в этом.

Работал с dns-записями, там были значки @, который как оказалось означает хост, всякие ДНС сервера, корпоративная почта, ttl, "_spf1=redirect", "verification" и т. д. Для меня это почти как китайский язык, почти ничего не понимал.

Как во всём этом разобраться, что читать/смотреть?

Answer (score 1):

Ответ сильно зависит от используемого инструмента. Если вам нужно поднять свой DNS сервер, то нужно читать инструкции к серверу (bind? windows dns? чтото ещё?), если использовать инструментарий хостинга - то читать инструкцию хостинга.

В целом - стандартом считается bind, так как он более распространён. Про теорию можно почитать [тут](https://habr.com/ru/post/137587/), быстро без воды о настройке bind - [тут](https://xakep.ru/2016/09/05/bind-9/). Про виндовый dns, например, [тут](https://serverspace.ru/support/help/configuring-a-dns-server-on-windows-server-2012-or-later/). У nic.ru есть услуга dns-хостинга, можно начинать читать [там](https://www.nic.ru/help/nastrojka-uslugi-dns-hosting_3491.html)

Comment: Спасибо, полезно. Прочитал не всё пока что, но уже узнал много нового.